# What is tc time at coalescence, ϕc phase at coalescence given in this following question ?for LIGO Data

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, gravitational-waves, ligo

I Am new to LIGO data

I was looking at the first solution for this question

[How were the solar masses and distance of the GW150914 merger event calculated from the signal?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/235579/how-were-the-solar-masses-and-distance-of-the-gw150914-merger-event-calculated-f?rq=1)

trying to reproduce a waveform for the LIGO merger. But I wasn't understanding the terms  t<sub>c</sub> time at coalescence, ϕ<sub>c</sub> phase at coalescence. I wanted to know how they can be determined by LIGO and how to use them to reproduce a waveform?

Answer (score 1):

Data is fitted with lots of templates each of them is moved forward in time and varied in phase to achieve the best match. When best match occurs at a certain time and phase this is coalesence time and phase.

They have no meaning when taken individually. But if $t_c$ and $\phi_c$ are considered for multiple detectors it informs about the relative arrival time of wave at different detectors and hence is used to localize the origin of the source.