# How to extract the masses from LIGO strain data?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, gravitational-waves, ligo

I am a Computer science student working on LIGO data. I have seen this well describing link

[How were the solar masses and distance of the GW150914 merger event calculated from the signal?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/235579/how-were-the-solar-masses-and-distance-of-the-gw150914-merger-event-calculated-f?rq=1)

On how to extract the masses from the data.

But I still find it a little difficult despite the good explanation. 
Can anyone give me a much simpler explanation on how to extract the masses from this data ?

A simple step by step solution would be really helpful

Thanks in advance

Comment: How exactly does your question differ from [the previous one](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/235579/how-were-the-solar-masses-and-distance-of-the-gw150914-merger-event-calculated-f)? Do you just want a from-the-ground-up tutorial on how to numerically simulate black-hole mergers in GR, and how to compare that with measured signals? That's too broad for this format.

Comment: I mean if theres a direct formula used which can give me a near approximation to the mass using the waveform that would be helpful as well

Comment: Or atleast a set of operations which I have to perform on the strain data to get the masses would be fine as well . If you can just list them out no need of even explanation . Just the workflow would be fine

Comment: The simple toy answer: You can extract it by maximizing the following quantity derived from Bayesian analysis: 
$(s|h(\mathbf{\theta}))-(h(\mathbf{\theta})|h(\mathbf{\theta}))$, where $s$ is the signal $\theta$ are the parameters of this waveform (e.g. chirp mass, distance, etc), $(a|b)=\int \frac{a b^*}{S_n(f)} df$ with $S_n$ being the power spectral density from the LIGO detector and 
$$
h(f) = \frac{1}{r}\mathcal{M}^{5/6}f^{-7/6}\exp(i\psi(f))
$$
$$
\psi(f) = 2\pi f t_c - \phi_c - \frac{\pi}{4} + \frac{3}{128}(\pi\mathcal{M}f)^{-5/3}
$$

**To first order approximation**

Comment: Alright. how do I determine time at Coalescence and phase at Coalescence ? Is it based on the waveform ? can we find these parameters in the waveform ?